# Prevent ajax submit function being called when it fails validation

Tags: 7, ajax, forms

I have a form, that when it's submitted, should be validated, and if valid, the results of that form should then appear below the form.

This works fine without AJAX:

```
function _form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if (!is_numeric($form_state['vsalues']['zip'])) {
    form_set_error('zip', 'Zip must be number');
  }
}

function _form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $values = $form_state['values'];
    $html = "<p>zip: ". $values['zip'] . "</p>";
    $form_state['storage'] = $html;
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
 }
```

and then this gets printed out my main form in

```
  $form['output'] = array(
    '#markup' => (isset($form_state['storage']))?$form_state['storage']:'',
  );
```

If I make it an AJAX form, and change the submit function to:

```
function _form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $values = $form_state['values'];
    $html = "<p>zip: ". $values['zip'] . "</p>";
    $form_state['storage'] = $html;
    $form_state['rebuild'] = FALSE;
    return array("#markup" => $html);
}
```

It works fine apart from the fact the submit callback is triggered even when validation fails (e.g. passing a non-numeric value shows both a validation error yet also prints "zip: ").

What am I doing wrong? How can I stop the submit function being called?

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error, I'll let you know if I find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Only thing you should have to put in your AJAX submit callback is this

```
  if (!form_get_errors()) {
    // Do your processing
  }
  else {
    // Return your form with errors.
   return $form;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I admitedly couldn't find an elegant solution for this but I found a decent workaround that solved my problem.

In my validation callback:

```
// Track errors and submissions ourselves.
$form_state['form_has_errors'] = FALSE;
$form_state['form_was_submitted'] = FALSE;

if ($condition) {
  form_set_error($form['fieldname'], t('Error message'));
  $form_state['form_has_errors'] = TRUE;
}
```

In the submit callback:

```
// Check for our custom error flag.
// For some reason form_get_errors() is empty, even when validation errors ocurred.
if (!$form_state['form_has_errors']) {
  // Put your submit callback code here.

  $form_state['form_was_submitted'] = TRUE;
}
```

In the AJAX callback:

```
if ($form_state['form_was_submitted']) {
  // Do something different here.
}
else {
  // For has errors and wasn't submitted.
}
```

Again, this is admittedly NOT an elegant solution but I couldn't find any other way to make Drupal not call the submit callback if errors were found.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put it in `hook_node_validate`. if your form is built using content type then it will definitely help you.

Another way might help you like, check it in `hook_node_presave()` and make exit() call if your validation got fails.

Answer (score 0):

Its an old issue, but i just worked on the same topic:

```
  // prevent default submit if form does not validate
  $('form').find('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function (e) {
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    if ( !($form[0].checkValidity && $form[0].checkValidity())) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
```

This is using the browser form validation which i used in a Drupal.behaviors function.